# Confused with output from for Loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I have to this code from an exercice book with 2 foor loops and an if statment  from which i cant understand the output!So i´m guessing that i dont understand how the for loop works  that well

```
class Multifor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {

            for (int y = 4; y > 2; y--) {
                System.out.println(x + " " + y);
            }
            if (x == 1) {
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
0 4,
0 3,
1 4,
1 3,
3 4,
3 3,
```

First question: How came x is twice 0 on the output if in the for loop it is incremented by 1 every time the code runs into the loop,by the time the code reachs the System.out.println part of the code it is alredy 1  , plus the incrementation of 1 in the if statment if x == 1; which would make the second output of x 2.

Second question:If y = 4 and it is decremented by 1 every time the for loop runs how is the output first 3 and then 4?? and so on if i don´t see any incrementation for the y variable?

Comment: Grab a pencil and paper or run it through a debugger and follow it line by line. There is nothing too complicated there so doing it manually by hand shouldn't be an issue, plus then you would be answering your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First question: How came x is twice 0 on the output if in the for loop
>   it is incremented by 1 every time the code runs into the loop,by the
>   time the code reachs the System.out.println part of the code it is
>   alredy 1 , plus the incrementation of 1 in the if statment if x == 1;
>   which would make the second output of x 2.

Each time you enter your main `x` loop, your inside loop `y` loops twice.

Also, when you enter your loop the first time, the value of `x` is the value you've assigned in the `for` declaration.

That's why the value of `x` only changes once in two prints.

> Second question:If y = 4 and it is decremented by 1 every time the for
>   loop runs how is the output first 3 and then 4?? and so on if i don´t
>   see any incrementation for the y variable?

The output of `y` is 4 then 3.

```
0 4
0 3
1 4
1 3
3 4
3 3
```

Comment: yes your right it starts with 4, but how does the y value keep getting incremented from 3 back to 4 again?

Comment: When you enter back the loop, the value of y goes back to 4 because of the 'int y = 4' ... If my answer helped you, don't hesitate validating it :)

Comment: yes ,i understand it clearly now ,thanks a lot ,your were a big help!

Answer (score 2):

For every value of x the inner loop of y will run two times.
first when y=4 then y=3,when y becomes 2 the condition become false as (y!>2),so it comes out the inner loop and then it will check the "if condition" that whether x is equal to 1 or not. If x is equal to 1 then value of x will be incremented to 2.
This continues until the condition in outer loop is True.
So the output will be like this:

`when x=0 y=4,3
when x=1 y=4,3
when x=3 y=4,3`

the sequence of output will be : 
`0 4 0 3 1 4 1 3 3 4 3 3`